# How can i run the index.jsp in different directory with apache?

Tags: java, apache, jsp

Question : How can i run the index.jsp in different directory? (refer pic below).

I'm successful to run the index.jsp file in (Community/WebContent/index.jsp) with this path http://localhost.:8080/Community/index.jsp

However wish to run the index.jsp in the webapp folder (Community/Serializer/src/main/webapp/index.jsp) with the same path.

I'm using eclipse, running apache-tomcat-7.0.28. Change on server.xml? Any Idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

put this path Community/Serializer/src/main/webapp/index.jsp in your wecome file of web.xml

Comment: <welcome-file>Serializer/src/main/webapp/index.jsp</welcome-file> has added to welcome file. However it seem still referring the previous root.<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>